# Help me to use 'Loop Cut' properly. Blender 2.8

Tags: loop

[image]

[image]

I use Blender 2.8. I read how to fix it on Blender 2.79, but i cant repeat their moves on Blender 2.8. I want to 'Loop Cut' cuts around my mesh.

Comment: This cut means that the next face is not really a quad or there is something doubled in the edge where the cut stops. So try things around 'merge by distance' with Alt+M (and former 'remove doubles').

Comment: He deleted 164 vertices, but it did not help

Comment: I selected all my mesh then pressed "ALT+M", choosed "By Distance"

Comment: I changed a liitle bit my mesh, but i still cannot to 'Loop Cut' this place ( place on an image ). How long it takes ? To upload .blend-file? I am waiting for 2 minutes

Comment: depends on the blend file and your internet upload rate... but this model seems to be small, apparently.

Comment: Faces are kind of "doubled"... to see that, select the face where the cut stops, then use H to hide it. That will make appear another face inside the mesh. Correcting that may be more or less long. Try to do it (or ping me later if you can not do it).

Comment: I saw but cant delete it correctly

Comment: Gave it a little try. Hide the face where the cut stops. Delete the face (face only) which appears under it. Alt + H to make the initial face to appear again. Try the loop cut again: you'll see that the loop cut is going further. So do it again with the next face.

Comment: But there is more complicated things inside... Globally your object geometry is not "good" (sorry to say). And that will lead to other problems... My advice: the shorter is to try to do it again (will be quicker than correct it, I think).

Comment: I made mesh for deck of guitar. After, i had to make a hole in this mesh. Also i used "Subdivision Surface". I created a circle to use "Knife Project". Made it and then deleted face. As u can saw, there are some triangles around this hole. If i remove "Subdivision surface" this triangles dissappear

Comment: It's due to the fact that you have extra vertices that don't connect to the outer mesh.  I suggest you re-cut the circle using a circle with 32 vertices, that way you don't have any extra vertices that don't connect anywhere.  If you don't understand, I'll clarify

Comment: Here is the corrected mesh. I kept the vertices, removed doubles and remade the faces. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6262" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6262/). Just a little help... go further and make your guitar! But be careful about double edges or faces or about vertices that are very closed (but doubled)

Comment: I am bad in English, so i didnt understand. Did you said that i must to use circle with 32 vertices or u said that i used circle with 32 vertices and it is bad ?

Comment: @lemon Yes, thanks for your help)) It would be greatfull if i could to ask you personally. If you dont mind

Comment: @RBlong2us as you know, when we create a circle, it is have 32 vertices, so i did not change count of vertices

Comment: This is not about 32 or other. This is about edges that were on each other. And ok, you could ask me (but I'm not always here...)

Comment: @lemon did you see another mesh in file that i send ? There is another mesh, and i have some troubles with it.

Comment: @Kaznachei, yes, there is, but as commented about your other question, this is "work", not a general question but a specific problem you should fix by yourself. So, I think, we can not help doing this work for you (even if I've done it above a bit). In hope you understand that.

Comment: Ok, i understand, thank you for remaking of mesh ))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96274/discussion-on-question-by-kaznachei-help-me-to-use-loop-cut-properly-blender).