# Subdivision Surface and Knife Project. Blender 2.8

Tags: loop

I made mesh for deck of guitar. After, I had to make a hole in this mesh. Also I used Subdivision Surface Modifier. I created a circle to use "Knife Project". Made in the mesh a circle then deleted face to make a hole. As u can see, there are some triangles around this hole. If K remove "Subdivision surface", these triangles disappear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: your topology must be bad, please show the wireframe

Comment: sorry your file makes my Blender crash, so someone else will help you  ;)

Comment: @moonboots should be 2.8... I was involved in another part https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145528/help-me-to-use-loop-cut-properly-blender-2-8?noredirect=1#comment248339_145528. This one is yours ; )

Comment: And, @Kaznachei yes, a guitar for a beginner is hard (it is hard for anyone, in fact).

Comment: it crashes with my 2.8   ;)

Comment: @moonboots, doesn't crash with 2.8RC (windows, downloaded today) here. But... no.. won't have time for this one.

Comment: Yes but i'm on mac and my 2.8 is several weeks old, i can't do anything unless he imports in 2.79, so maybe help Kaznachel if you have time  ;)

Comment: @moonboots, well... no sorry, won't have more time. Sorry Karnachei, but at some moment you'll need to fly by yourself. The problem is (ok we can help) but what you're asking is very specific (so a bit out of what can be done here, generally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem you mentioned in the comments is because of these little straggler vertices that aren't connected to the mesh like the others.

[image: stragglers]

So to fix that you can start by deleting this ring of faces:

[image: delete]

Next, you create a new circle, place it where you want the hole, select the circle and the rim of the guitar created by the deleting of faces, hit ctrl-E, and select "bridge Edge loops".

And here is the result:

[image: bridge]

It's definitely not as pretty, but there doesn't seem to be any intersections or anything, and it does get the problem fixed.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank u. It really helps me)) Learned the secret of universe))